# Are there any journals where I can publish a research proposal?

Tags: journals, biology

Just curious, are there any journals  where I can publish research proposals?

I know there is one (Research Ideas and Outcomes) out there, but are there any others?

Comment: Sorry, journal recommendations or requests for journals meeting some criteria are out of scope of this site. See the [help/on-topic] for details.

Comment: I believe this question should be reopened, as the heart of the question is not "which journal is best for proposals" but rather "do *any* journals exist for publishing proposals", which deserves a Yes/No answer, perhaps with one example.

Comment: @WetlabWalter I think the OP is already aware of one example: "Research Ideas and Outcomes" and  is looking for any others.

Comment: Ah, fair enough. Then yeah that's no good :)